# CloudKit | User deleting all iCloud data inside Settings also resets local core-data store?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I'm facing the problem below:

When the user decides to delete all iCloud data inside settings, automatically, all local core-data savings are deleted as well.

After some debugging, I could find out that this exactly happens after the first time I initialize an `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. So somehow the merge happens to reset the local data?

I have also made a dummy project using the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. I could observe this behaviour as well, which makes me conclude that this happens by default?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I could tell you the details if you wish, I just don't know what I should include.

### Update

Could this be intended?

[image]

It says this action **will also delete all data stored on this iPhone**.

But what if the user only whats to clean some iCloud space?

### Interesting

From testing many real-world applications - part of them shows the behavior of losing all local data as well. But there is also a decent amount of apps keeping the local data after the reset.

I also tested it with apples own Clips app. All local-data were gone as well.